# Vue.Draggable for tables with more than one tbody

Tags: javascript, vue.js, drag-and-drop, draggable

I have table with difficult structure. The real structure of my table is much more difficult.
I try to show it by a simple example.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr colspan="2">
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr colspan="2">
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I use vuejs, and I need to have sortable table (I use vuedraggable component https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable).

I have item component with template like this.

```
<template>
    <tbody class="item">
        <tr>
            <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr colspan="2">
            <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</template>
```

And I use it with draggable.

```
<draggable v-model="items" :element="'table'" :options="{draggable: '.item'}">
    <item-component v-for="(item, index) in items" :item="item" :key="item.id">
    </item-component>
</draggable>
```

The Draggable component create outer 'table' element. Everything is working, but how can I add 'thead'?

I try to create one more component - items:

```
<template>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
        </thead>
        <slot></slot>
    </table>    
</template>
```

But this is not working:

```
<draggable v-model="items" :element="items-component" :options="{draggable: '.item'}">
    <item-component v-for="(item, index) in items" :item="item" :key="item.id">
    </item-component>
</draggable>
```

Answer (score -1):

Since `VueDraggable` is a custom component, when using the DOM as your template eg. `table` you will be subject to some restrictions that are inherent to how HTML works, because Vue can only retrieve the template content after the browser has parsed and normalized it.

This will lead to issues when using custom components with elements that have such restrictions

A workaround is to use the `is` special attribute:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
  </thead>
<div is="draggable" element="div" v-model="items">
  <tbody v-for="i in items">
    <tr>
      <td>{{i.id}}</td>
      <td>{{i.name}}</td>
    </tr>
     <tr colspan="2">
        <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</div>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think my problem is in another. I need to have more than one tbody. Because for each item I have some 'tr'.
I need to sort tbody between themselves.
Draggable component have :element property and always create outer HTML DOM container for himself.

Comment: Sure, I have tried to create a <div> tag between <table> and <tbody>. It works in my situation.

Comment: For me it is not working (. Div is in the table. It is unacceptable. Table breaks and table header do not work. (